# ocaml write match sequent function

Tags: ocaml, substitution

I have to write a function
`match_sequent` with 4 parameters :

1. first sequent
2. second sequent
3. optional subst Γ, with type `form list option`
4. list subst of Var

and return optional subst Γ and a list of Var.

We have some defined types:

```
type unop = Neg
type binop = Conj | Disj | Impl | Equiv

type form = 
  Const of bool
| Var of string
| Unop of unop * form
| Binop of binop * form * form

type sequent = Seq of form list * form
```

I wrote a function `match_form` that matches two forms and calculates a subst if it exists.

like this :

```
let rec match_form = function
   ((Const c1,Const c2)::e,sbst)->
     if c1=c2 then match_form(e,sbst)
.....
.....
.....

let form1 = Binop(Conj,Var "a",Var "b");; (* a/\b *)

let form2 = Binop(Conj, Binop(Disj, Const true, Const false), Const true);; (* ((p\/q)/\r) *)

(* Test match_form *)

match_form([(form1, form2)],[]);;
(* Output 
- : (string * form) list = 
    [("a", Binop (Disj, Const true, Const false)); ("b", Const true)]
*)
```

But really I'm struggling with this function `match_sequent`.

I try to deal with it but I have no idea how I can do that.

```
let rec match_sequent (s1 : sequent) (s2 : sequent) ?sopt svar = 
   match s1,s2 with 

   |.....;;
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: could you please give us an concrete example?

Comment: Also is `subst` "substitution"? or "subset"?

Comment: `optional subst Γ, with type form list option` what do you mean by the last "option"? Does it mean the type `option`, i.e., `Some ... / None`? If so, then in your `match_sequent`, you either to give `sopt` `option` type or give a default value if you want to define an optional parameter `?sopt:(sopt = ...)`. http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/u3-ocaml/ocaml051.html

Comment: I have tried, unless you describe your problem more clearly, i can't continue. I don't know the goal of the match.

Comment: subst is substitution

Comment: option is optional , but is needed to use in another function match_sequent_list to calculate a substitution between two list of sequent

Comment: This "sequent" is from [sequent calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent), right? So you're trying to do the same *unification* you made on formulas with sequent equations, aren't you?

Comment: The purpose of `svar` eludes me however, is that supposed to be the result?

Comment: yes i think **sopt** and **svar** that supposed to be the result

Comment: yes is form sequent calculs

Comment: Check out cs.stackexchange.com you might want to ask over there instead of here for more theory oriented CS questions.

Answer (score 1):

If my understanding is correct, you wish to unify two sequent calculus formulas, each made of first order logic formulas, for which you already have an unification algorithm.

From this premise, it's relatively straightforward to implement the algorithm: recall that a sequent formula is a formula whose "left hand side" is a conjunction of first order logic formulas (or forms as you named them) expressed as a tuple (the *∧* operator is implicit), and the right hand side, in your case, a single form (though it might theorically be a disjunction of formulas). Unification is therefore just unifying each pair of corresponding forms from the sequents.

```
let match_sequent s1 s2 ?sopt svar =
    match s1, s2 with
    Seq (lhs1,rhs1), Seq(lhs2,rhs2) -> 
    List.fold_left2 (fun l f1 f2 -> match_form (f1,f2)::l) [] (rhs1::lhs1) (rhs2::lhs2)
```

My "guess" with regard to `svar` and/or `sopt` is that you would need to check that existing substitutions are not incompatible with the ones found by unification: that would require to compare the latter and the former, and for matching variable names, verify that their substitutions are either equals or that one is more general than the other, and keep the less general one.

Also note that the above algorithm is expecting  lhs forms to have the exact same shape, so if `lhs1` is simply *a* it will not unify with a `lhs2` of *b,c* although *b,c* literally means *b∧c*, and would unify with *a* in first order logic. If your algorithm requires this unification to be acceptable, I suggest making the conjunction explicit  by combining the lhs forms into a single one and then apply `match_form` unification on them.

```
let match_sequent (Seq (lhs1,rhs1)) (Seq (lhs2,rhs2)) ?opt svar =
    match lhs1,lhs2 with
      f1::lhs1, f2::lhs2 -> 
(match_form (List.fold_left conj f1 lhs1) (List.fold_left conj f2 lhs2)) @ (match_form rhs1 rhs2)
    | [], lhs
    | lhs, [] -> (* empty premises for at least one of the sequent *)
        match_form rhs1 rhs2
```

Where `conj` is a function constructing a *conjunction* of formulas:

```
val conj: form -> form -> form
```

Again, the last parameters need to be integrated in the algorithm somehow.

One last consideration I would like to point out is that *a∧b∧c* could be written in 2 different ways, depending on the application ordering of the *∧* operators in there. I suppose that either your `match_form` function or the `conj` pseudo constructor take care of rebalancing formulas to a "normal form".

Comment: I don't really feel comfortable with this answer as it is right now. hopefully someone more knowledgeable than me on the topic will step up and give a better answer or correct mine.

Comment: `conj` is a function you will have to write, the simplest implementation is a simple wrapper for the `Conj` constructor, but as I said in my answer, there will probably be issues to sort out wrt operator associativity.